# Sending e-mail without postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page with a contact-us form located at the bottom.

What I am trying to achieve - send an email from the site without post back that'll reload all the page and move the customer to the top of the page(the contact-us form is at the bottom).

Instead of that - The customer will press the send button, and then some gesture that the mail was sent will appear.

I know how to send mail with the  regular approach, what I am trying to accomplish is to send it 
from the client side with jquery.ajax - is it the best way for that scenario?

What I did was that, **Client side:**

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {       
    var fullName = $('#txt_fullName').val();
    var fromEmail = $('#txt_email').val();
    var comments = $('#txtArea_message').val();
    var fromPhone = $('#txt_phone').val();
    var data = "{'name': '" + name + "', 'fromEmail': '" +
           fromEmail + "', 'comments': '" + comments + "', 'fromPhone': '" + fromPhone + "'}";

    if (contactus == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/sentMail",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        })
    }else if (contactus == 1)
        return false;
})
```

**In the server side i have this:**

```
string sender_email = txt_email.Text;
    string sender_fullName = txt_fullName.Text;
    string sender_phone = txt_phone.Text;
    string sender_message = txtArea_message.Text;

    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
    MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com", "Site");
    MyMailMessage.To.Add("XXX@gmail.com");
    MyMailMessage.Subject = "messge from site";
    MyMailMessage.Body = "message";
    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);          
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```